# Alternative to iframe.onload?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

### COMPLETE EDIT

So I create an iframe and it's supposed to continue reloading after a function runs. The function reads info that is in the iframe. Currently I have something like this (Which works);

```
function loaded(){
    alert(iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("blah")[0].innerHTML);
    iframe.src = filePath; //reloads the iframe
}

iframe.onload = loaded;
```

As an alternative, would something like this work, where the function runs as soon as the iframe has loaded the DOM;

```
function loaded(){
    alert(iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("blah")[0].innerHTML);
    iframe.src = filePath; //reloads the iframe
}

iframe.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);
```

Comment: is the iframe content on the same domain? if it is can you edit the content?

Comment: Yes. I have no problems running the function. But I want it to run as soon as possible.

Comment: load must be a function reference not a function call, please remove () and could you please say does your code run on the page or inside iframe?

Comment: Edited the whole question

Comment: Not this way - from your code snippet I am guessing that iframe is a reference do a Dom element - if it is - then no iframe.addEventListener ... will not work, please refer to my anwser again ... you need to write window.addEventListener ... I will edit my anwser for a bit more clarity

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly (iframe is on the same domain and you can edit its content), you can add this in your iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   fireOnReadyEvent();
   parent.loaded();
//]]>
</script>
```

This will call the loaded function in the parent page once the iframe is ready. And you can remove `iframe.onload = loaded;` from the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is a DomContentLoaded event (check out your chrome dev tools for a blue line :) )

You can listen for this event like this

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Its unclear though whether you want to access frame window object from inside the frame or outside... if from outside ... you need `window.frames['SOME_FRAME_ID']` and `document.getElementById('SOME_FRAME_ID').contentWindow` for firefox to access frame window object.

For IE use fallback

```
window.attachEvent('onload', loaded);
```

And remember when working with frames - something will go horribly wrong

EDIT UPDATE

Suppose you have a frame

```
<iframe src="" id="myFavouriteFrame" ...>
```

Here goes some code

```
var iframeId = 'myFavouriteFrame';
var iframeWindow = null;

if(window.all && !window.opera) {
    iframeWindow = window.frames[iframeId];
}
else {
    iframeWindow = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow; //Note - not standard
}

if(iframeWindow && iframeWindow.addEventListener) {
    iframeWindow.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);
}
else if (iframeWindow && iframeWindow.attachEvent){
    iframeWindow.attachEvent('onload', load);
}
```

Comment: iframe.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false); --Isnt working

Comment: ofcourse not, you need window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false); where window - global object of the frame

Comment: Edited my original question